# How do I solve a quadratic inequality with absolute value using cases?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

$$\left| x^{ 2 }-5x+5 \right| \le x$$

Steps I took:

Using the quadratic formula, I split the solutions up into:

Case 1:

$$ x^{ 2 }-5x+5\le 0$$

$$x\le \frac { 5+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } and\quad x\ge \frac { 5-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } $$

$$x\le \frac { 5-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } and\quad x\ge \frac { 5+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } $$

$$\frac { 5-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } \le x\le \frac { 5+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } $$

Case 2:

$$x^{ 2 }-5x+5>0$$

$$\Rightarrow x>\frac { 5+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } \quad and\quad x>\frac { 5-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } $$

$$\Rightarrow x<\frac { 5+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } \quad and\quad x<\frac { 5-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } $$

$$\Rightarrow x<\frac { 5-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } \quad and\quad x>\frac { 5+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } $$

I feel lost at this point. I don't know what I need to do exactly. Please note that I would like to learn to solve this using the separate case method, so do not suggest a different method.

I imagine that I need to try one of the cases, so case 2 would be:

$$ x^{ 2 }-5x+5 \le x$$

$$\Rightarrow x^{ 2 }-6x+5 \le 0 $$

$$\Rightarrow (x-5)(x-1)\le 0 $$

So, my possible solution are $$x \le 5 \quad and \quad x \ge 1, \quad x \ge 5 \quad and \quad x \le 1 $$

Comment: You might try graphing both $|x^2-5x+5|$ and $x$ on the same graph.  That might help you get your head around it.

Comment: Mod should be taken out with +,- signs use them and i think you should get it.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I have graphed it... I would just like to know how I should proceed from here. I know the case 1 is invalid as per the graph.

Comment: @Macavity my case one would be $-x^{ 2 }+4x-5\le 0$ which does not coincide with what I established beforehand. Right?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Please explain what you mean

Comment: Ya now we have  confirmed that only one case exists and the range of x is what you get from case 2. Hope now i am clear.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Yes, but the range of case 2 does not coincide. I get that it can be $\Rightarrow x<\frac { 5-\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 } \quad and\quad x>\frac { 5+\sqrt { 5 }  }{ 2 }$, but then I get that $1 \le x \le 5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 : You have to solve
$$-(x^2-5x+5)\le x$$and $$\frac{5-\sqrt 5}{2}\le x\le\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}.$$

Case 2 : You have to solve
$$x^2-5x+5\le x$$
and
$$x\lt \frac{5-\sqrt 5}{2}\quad \text{$\color{red}{\text{or}}$}\quad x\gt\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}.$$

Comment: The first case has no solutions.
 I don't get what I am doing with the second case. I get that $1 \le x \le 5$.

How does that match the solution set for it?

Comment: @nikolita: "The fist case has no solutions" is not correct. $-(x^2-5x+5)\le x$,i.e. $x^2-4x+5\ge 0$ is always true. So, for the first case, we have $\frac{5-\sqrt 5}{2}\le x\le\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}$. For the second case, we have $1\le x\lt \frac{5-\sqrt 5}{2}$ or $\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}\lt x\le 5$.

Comment: That's not the solution set I get when this gets plugged into wolfram alpha...

Comment: @nikolita: By the way, the final solution is $1\le x\le 5$.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just don't get how I go from getting the solution sets of both cases to $1\le x\le 5$

Comment: @nikolita: The final solution is $1\le x\le 5$ because the solution for the first case is $\frac{5-\sqrt 5}{2}\le x\le \frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}$ and the solution for the second case is $1\le x\lt \frac{5-\sqrt 5}{2}$ or $\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2}\lt x\le 5$. Just combine them. So, it seems that you don't understand solutions for cases.

Comment: That probably is the case. I did a few problems with cases for absolute value already, but this problem is giving me issues. I can't put two and two together.

Comment: @nikolita: Plotting the solutions on a number line should help. See for example [here](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ate6/quadinequal.htm).

Comment: So, for get the intersection of case 1, get the intersection of case 2, and combine them?

Comment: @nikolita: Yes, exactly. (be careful about the difference between "and" and "or")

Comment: One final question, do I take the intersection or union of the solution set when I solve for the negative and positive of the expression in the absolute value?

Comment: @nikolita: "and" is "intersection", and "or" is "union" in each case (see my answer). Then, finally, take the union of the solutions for both cases. (because case 1 "or" case 2) Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way to solve the problem. If $x<0$, then the equation does not have solution. If $x\ge0$, the equation is equivalent to 
$$-x\le x^{ 2 }-5x+5\le x. $$
Note that $-x\le x^{ 2 }-5x+5$ is always true for any $x$. Solving $x^{ 2 }-5x+5\le x$ gives $1\le x\le 5$. Combining this with $x\ge0$, you can obtain the solution set 
$$ \{x: 1\le x\le 5\}=[1,5]. $$

Comment: I want to use the two cases I established the revolve around the absolute value...